# Multiple collapsable lists with just html/css

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create something you can click, and it will expand a list, click again and it should collapse. I want to do this without jquery/javascript. The code I found here gave me exactly what I needed, with one problem, having multiple different expanding lists. When a second list is added, clicking the first will result in them both opening, but just clicking the 2nd will only expand/collapse itself(the desired outcome). Is there anyway to accomplish this without adding an ungodly amount of CSS ?

```css
    [id^="togList"] ~ .list,
    /* HIDE LIST */
    [id^="togList"] + label span + span,
    /* HIDE "Collapse" */
    [id^="togList"]:checked + label span {
      /* HIDE "Expand" (IF CHECKED) */
      display: none;
    }
    [id^="togList"]:checked + label span + span {
      display: inline-block;
      /* SHOW "Collapse" (IF CHECKED) */
    }
    [id^="togList"]:checked ~ .list {
      display: block;
      /* SHOW LIST (IF CHECKED) */
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input id="togList1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList1">
    <a href="h">Planets</a>
    <span>˅</span>
    <span>˄</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <p>whatever mutho.</p>
  </div>
  <input id="togList2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList2">
    <a href="h">Banana Hammock</a>
    <span>˅</span>
    <span>˄</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <p>numba 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[id^="togList"]:checked ~ .list
```

This will apply `display: block` to every `.list` after the checked check-box.

For pure CSS tabs I would recommend to check this article about [Functional CSS Tabs](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/)

If you really like your example, then you just need to wrap every group. See my example:

```css
 [id^="togList"] ~ .list,
 /* HIDE LIST */
 [id^="togList"] + label span + span,
 /* HIDE "Collapse" */
 [id^="togList"]:checked + label span {
   /* HIDE "Expand" (IF CHECKED) */
   display: none;
 }
 [id^="togList"]:checked + label span + span {
   display: inline-block;
   /* SHOW "Collapse" (IF CHECKED) */
 }
 [id^="togList"]:checked ~ .list {
   display: block;
   /* SHOW LIST (IF CHECKED) */
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input id="togList1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList1">
    <a href="h">Planets</a>
    <span>˅</span>
    <span>˄</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <p>whatever mutho.</p>
  </div></div>
  <div>
  <input id="togList2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList2">
    <a href="h">Banana Hammock</a>
    <span>˅</span>
    <span>˄</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <p>numba 2.</p>
  </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have been struggling with a couple different methods of accomplishing this for days, much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change to
[id^="togList"]:checked + label + .list

```css
[id^="togList"] ~ .list,
/* HIDE LIST */
[id^="togList"] + label span + span,
/* HIDE "Collapse" */
[id^="togList"]:checked + label span {
  /* HIDE "Expand" (IF CHECKED) */
  display: none;
}
[id^="togList"]:checked + label span + span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* SHOW "Collapse" (IF CHECKED) */
}
[id^="togList"]:checked + label + .list {
  display: block;
  /* SHOW LIST (IF CHECKED) */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input id="togList1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList1">
    <a href="h">Planets</a>
    <span>˅</span>
    <span>˄</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <p>whatever mutho.</p>
  </div>
  <input id="togList2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="togList2">
    <a href="h">Banana Hammock</a>
    <span>˅</span>
    <span>˄</span>
  </label>
  <div class="list">
    <p>numba 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```